# How to fix IncompatibleClassChangeError during Android Jackson Parsing using annotations in Android Lollipop?

Tags: android, json, parsing, jackson, android-5.0-lollipop

In our android app, we use Jackson Annotations in our models:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "templateType", visible = true, defaultImpl = Default.class)
@JsonSubTypes({
@Type(value = Subclass1.class, name = "tType1")
```

We parse the json response using object mapper where klass is the class of the object file which we wish to parse to:
`getObjectMapper().readValue(json, klass);`

On rare scenarios on Android Lollipop devices, we get

`java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Couldn't find com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes$Type.value.`

Full stack trace:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes$Type.value
at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.toAnnotationInstance(AnnotationAccess.java:659)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredAnnotations(Class.java:891)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass.resolveClassAnnotations(AnnotatedClass.java:300)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.isIgnorableType(JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.java:103)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.isIgnorableType(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:844)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer2(DeserializerCache.java:401)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findContextualValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:305)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.createContextual(CollectionDeserializer.java:151)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.findDeserializer(StdDeserializer.java:634)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.resolve(BeanDeserializerBase.java:438)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.TypeDeserializerBase._findDeserializer(TypeDeserializerBase.java:173)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer._deserializeTypedForId(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:99)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserializeWithType(AbstractDeserializer.java:106)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:464)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:98)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:295)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2888)
```

Comment: Can you add your dependency (gradle) configuration? Sounds like you have two incompatible versions of Jackson in the dependency list.

Comment: @dhke this is currently happening only on our Lollipop phones. Can you help me understand why you think it's wo incompatible versions of Jackson in the dependency list?

Comment: I'm more or less guessing based on the error message. It could also be a problem with *dex* not properly handling the inner class. Or it could be a (quite) old version of jackson interfering with your intended version.

Comment: Do you use proguard?

Comment: I think I'm seeing this issue as well, at least similar one. Only on Samsung Lolipop phones. Were you able to track it down and solve it?

Answer (score 18):

This is a confirmed bug on some Samsung devices. Unfortunately there is no fix yet, but this Android Bug Tracker thread will probably come up with a fix (if possible) soon:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=172339

Comment: I'm seeing this also on Samsung 5.x phones, but with Google Gson library. Appears to be a rare flukey thing. I have no hope for a framework fix that Samsung would pull in and patch to all their phones. So any advice on a workaround would be most helpful.

Comment: if you find the solution then please post here, i m also stuck here

Comment: Happens to us also with Jackson2 & Samsung 5.x Only. Greg/Sameer have you found any workaround?

Comment: @MaximRahlis, no dear, i have found any solution yet.

Comment: Do any of you use multidex?

Comment: Same issue here. Thousands of error on my crash console. Any hints how to mitigate the problem?

Comment: @MaximRahlis yes to multidex