# Sigend APK with proguard gives IncompatibleClassChangeError

Tags: android, kotlin, android-proguard, fasterxml

Im trying to run signed apk with proguard at it gives me

**IncompatibleClassChangeError** error during runtime on fasterxml deserialization part.

this is error log :

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Couldn't find kotlin.Metadata.bv
at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.toAnnotationInstance(AnnotationAccess.java:659)
at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.annotationSetToAnnotations(AnnotationAccess.java:633)
at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.getDeclaredAnnotations(AnnotationAccess.java:161)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredAnnotations(Class.java:743)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ClassUtil.findClassAnnotations(:1095)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClassResolver.resolveClassAnnotations(:154)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClassResolver.resolveFully(:118)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClassResolver.resolve(:69)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector._resolveAnnotatedClass(:282)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.collectProperties(:192)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.forDeserialization(:112)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.forDeserialization(:16)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationConfig.introspect(:731)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(:324)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(:264)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(:244)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(:142)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(:477)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(:4190)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(:4009)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(:3023)
at com.khcai.mifrooshe.deserializers.AppVersionHitoryModelDeserializer.a(:25)
at com.khcai.mifrooshe.networking.GetAppVersionHistoryClient.a(:39)
at com.khcai.mifrooshe.activity.HomeActivity$versionChangeLog$1.a(:277)
at com.khcai.mifrooshe.activity.HomeActivity$versionChangeLog$1.invoke(:62)
at org.jetbrains.anko.AsyncKt$doAsync$1.invoke(:140)
at org.jetbrains.anko.AsyncKt$doAsync$1.invoke()
at org.jetbrains.anko.AsyncKt$sam$Callable$761a5578.call()
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:154)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

and my proguard setting :

```
-ignorewarnings
-keep class * {
    public private *;
}

-keep class kotlin.reflect.** { *; }

-keepclassmembers class ** extends com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.** {
   public <init>(...);
}

-keepclassmembers class ** extends com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.** {
   public <init>(...);
}


-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.yalantis.ucrop**
-keep class com.yalantis.ucrop** { *; }
-keep interface com.yalantis.ucrop** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }

-keepattributes *Annotation*,EnclosingMethod,Signature
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.**
-keep class org.codehaus.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers public final enum org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect$Visibility {
    public static final org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect$Visibility *; }
-keep public class your.class.** {
    public void set*(***);
    public *** get*();
}
```

and package list in gradle file :

```
  buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation (name:'rangeseekbar-debug', ext:'aar')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0'
    implementation "com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0"
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:$anko_version"
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.9.8'
    implementation 'com.github.ittianyu:BottomNavigationViewEx:1.2.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.2.5'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
    implementation 'com.github.esafirm.android-image-picker:imagepicker:1.12.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
    implementation 'com.github.hamsaadev:Persian-Date-Picker-Dialog:V1.2'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.firdausmaulan:GlideSlider:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.2'
    implementation('io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Project runs fine when i use debug setting or remove the proguard with set these

to **minifyEnabled**,**shrinkResources**,**useProguard** to false.

even this guide didnt help :

[update README.md to include proguard rule for kotlin.reflect](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin/pull/164/commits/c6d469db82d2af6471da550fc500850ccc7edf08)

Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try removing "-keep class kotlin.reflect.** { *; }" from the proguard rule @Ahad

Comment: Or just keep "-dontwarn kotlin.**" this in proguard instead of "-keep class kotlin.reflect.** { *;"

Comment: @g.brahmaDatta I've tried your suggestion and replaced that line with "-dontwarn kotlin.**" but still getting the same error.

Comment: try this "-keep class kotlin.Metadata { *; }" and let me know @Ahad

Comment: @g.brahmaDatta after chaning to your suggestion error changed to this : "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getAnnotationsByType(Ljava/lang/Class;)[Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation; in class Ljava/lang/reflect/Field; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.lang.reflect.Field' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar) at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.KotlinAnnotationIntrospector"

Comment: Oh i'm sorry.I think you are not using those methods in Project. I got similar errors.I got rid of that when I checked each and every warning and removed unnecessary rules in proguard.

Comment: I have used -dontwarn kotlin.Metadata and -keep class kotlin.Metadata { *; }
 in my code and i got successful signed apk

Comment: @g.brahmaDatta still getting error :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are seeing this on a Samsung Android 5.x device then this is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30355502/85472

Additional to that answer is also this [issue filed on the jackson kotlin repo](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin/issues/208).